# How to tell Proguard to obfuscate specific dead code

Tags: obfuscation, proguard

I have code that appears dead in its Java project, but it's being called elsewhere. How do I tell Proguard to ignore it during the shrinking stage and *still* obfuscate it?

It seems that you can either shrink or not shrink (all code or nothing). Is there a way to not shrink on specific class member names?

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve entry points but still obfuscate them with the option `-keep,allowobfuscation`. That is very unusual though, since changing their names to meaningless strings makes it practically very difficult to use them.

See ProGuard manual > Usage > [Keep options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions)